# How to build the request for a long poll url for box.com

Tags: long-polling, box-api, python-3.3

I'm writing a python script that follows the instructions here (https://developers.box.com/using-long-polling-to-monitor-events/) and have run into a snag.  I can get the next starting point, but can't seem to get the long poll url.

I am GETting this url (https://api.box.com/2.0/events -X OPTIONS) and I'm using the appropriate authentication header, of course.  Based on the instructions, I am looking for the long polling url in the `['entries']['url']` section of the json response to my request.

What I am getting, though, is this:  json response:

```
{'code': 'not_found', 
 'status': 404, 
 'request_id': '2064100451fad3cd2cc24', 
 'type': 'error', 
 'message': 'Not Found'}
```

Either I'm not building my url correctly by tacking `-X OPTIONS` on the end, or something is wrong with the instructions.  I'm kinda betting on me not reading the instructions correctly, so any clues would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by Reading The Fine Manual.  I interpreted box.com's instructions to indicate I needed to tack "OPTIONS" on the end of the url I sent to them, when what I really needed to do was use the "OPTIONS" http verb.

While CURL wants you to put your HTTP verb at the end of the command line, Python builds a URL in the traditional way.  So, if you need to tell box.com you want to use the options verb, you build your url to use options where you would normally use get, put, post, etc.